# Do you announce when you have lost due to Insanity?

Tags: mansions-of-madness

I was playing mansions of madness 2nd edition and I got the 'selfish motives' insanity card. The next turn I became wounded, meaning I lost.

When this happens, do you announce that you have lost? Do you keep playing? It just seems odd playing as normal now that my character has lost

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your insanity condition is secret, and you are forced to keep it secret**.  The rules state it cannot be revealed to the other players for any reason, unless some other event tells you to.

So even if you have been put into situation where it is impossible for you to fulfill your personal Insane win condition, your investigator hasn't been eliminated and the game hasn't ended.  Your insanity, and your win-lose status, remains secret, and the other players will continue to eyeball you and wonder what you're really going to be up to.  This may or may not affect how quickly they can complete the investigation, so it is still important.

Comment: My set is put away at the moment, so I don't have the text of Selfish Motives, or know if there's any possible card that can remove a Wound.  The game rules are pretty clear though - only player elimination forces the last round of the game, and insanity is kept secret unless something specific happens.  I'll see if I can check card texts later and clarify anything else.